# What does Google mean by "The full body of the article"

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, json-ld

If I'm wanting to enable article rich snippets on a page using JSON, [Google says to do this:](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles)

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "headline": "Article headline",
  "alternativeHeadline": "The headline of the Article",
  "image": ["thumbnail1.jpg", "thumbnail2.jpg"],
  "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
  "description": "A most wonderful article",
  "articleBody": "The full body of the article"
}
</script>
```

Under `articleBody` it says to place `The full body of the article`. Does that literally mean the entire article from beginning to end?

Comment: JSON-LD allows you to script your code, so you can create a script that writes the JSON-LD and dynamically assigns articleBody for you. 
Edit- given that microdata is preferred you could add a tiny amount of microdata to the body tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does mean all of your article. This will certainly be used by search engines to index the content of your article and allow users to search on it.

Also avoid to have any html tags within this.

Comment: Any references to where it says that html should/n't be used within the `articleBody` ?

Comment: You can use them as long as they're escaped. And this only applies to JSON. If you use html that isn't escaped properly, it will break the script.

Comment: So basically if you put this on your article page, you duplicate the whole body?